# PhD from Third Tier School

Tags: phd, graduate-school

I am interested in doing a PhD from a third tier school in Electrical Engineering Ranked about in the 60's in North America.

I have degrees (Bachelors, Masters) from a Top 20 North American School.

Is this advisable or even worth it ?

The supervisor is not very well known in the industry in this field but is somewhat known in academia in this field.

In my field, companies will only hire from Top 20 schools.

I would like to stay in academia after graduating after being in industry for a few years.

So is this going backwards then ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do the graduates of that program (and more specifically, students of that supervisor) go on to get jobs you would want?

Comment: Yes, but not at the top companies as they will only hire from Top 20 schools.

Comment: You said you want to stay in academia - why do companies of any type matter? (though I think you are very wrong about any company having a "top 20" requirement...) I reiterate my comment: do graduates go on to get jobs you would want?

Comment: I am under the assumption top companies will provide research funding to top schools, as they would only hire top graduates from certain universities.  Not all companies of course, but the top tier ones - yes, you can get the kind of jobs I want, but maybe not at the top 5 companies.

Comment: Why rely on assumptions? What are alumni from the program doing?

Comment: Top 60 according to who? I bet there are 60 schools that say they are in the top 20. What type of ranking has 60 as third tier?

Comment: I think you are mistaken about rankings. The total output of the "top 20" schools is so small that all those companies would close with no one left to hire and salaries would be in the millions. It is a tiny number of doctoral graduates you are talking about.

Comment: Rankings are according to websites that do Rankings.  For example one of them is: https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2019/engineering-electrical-electronic

Comment: The ranking of the school isn't what makes your career. I've known people from CMU that I wouldn't hire. I know of people from Harvard and Yale that I'd never consider for any responsible position.

Comment: The group at the PhD school is small and is mostly a place where people get Masters Degrees then get PhDs at top 20 schools.

Comment: @sheeple For the people that do get PhDs there, where do they go afterwards?

Comment: The PhD graduates have either gone on to work in industry but not in the top companies or in academia at lower tier schools.  The research group is not very well known in either sphere - so I am wondering if it is worth it and how it will be viewed in either industry or academia.

Comment: Well, I would never call a R1 university a third tier, and also, there are some research groups, and specially lab/institutes, in the 100s range that put forth a lot of research and are well know in their field. Looking for a **best in EE** university will not give you the same results as a best in _identification of nonlinear systems subject to data rate constrains_, PhD are incomparable by ranks alone.

Comment: @jDAQ, this PhD school is not a R1 university.

Comment: @sheeple There are way more than 60 R1 universities in the US. I'd have a hard time believing a #60s school is not an R1.

Comment: @BryanKrause - that's #60 according to this ranking.

Comment: @sheeple Then that #60 doesn't seem very meaningful (and kind of what StrongBad was getting at earlier about rankings). Wikipedia has a list at least of US R1 schools, I don't know if that designation is considered outside the US: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_research_universities_in_the_United_States - yours is outside this list?

Comment: Yes it is outside this list.

Comment: you should re-evaluate what metrics you are looking at, how you understand rankings, and where you information comes from. I would pose a counter to your point, how many companies can you name that refuse to hire someone with a PhD from Princeton, Cornell, Columbia, or University of Michigan, because they are not "top 20 schools".

Comment: according to the rankings i posted in previous comments above - those are top 20 schools in north america in electrical engineering.

Answer (score 2):

> I am interested in doing a PhD from a third tier school in Electrical Engineering Ranked about in the 60's in North America.
>
> In my field, companies will only hire from Top 20 schools.
>
> I would like to stay in academia after graduating after being in industry for a few years.

Assuming all of the above are true, then clearly this is a bad idea, because if you go to this school then you won't be in the top 20 and won't get hired and have no chance of "being in industry for a few years".

Comment: A sound application of *modus ponens*, indeed.  Although it is reasonable here to question the OP's hypotheses...

Comment: True, it might be flawed logic, but I am just going by the evidence.